# Laravel: 'null value in column "password" violates not-null constraint' even though password is definitely provided

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel, eloquent

I'm building a GraphQL API in Laravel 5.5 and I'm getting an error back from `User::create()` that says that I did not provide a value for the 'password' column, even though I definitely did. This is the full message from `User::create()`:

```
SQLSTATE[23502]: Not null violation: 7 ERROR:  null value in column \"password\" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (507, null, null, 2017-09-23 14:12:11, 2017-09-23 14:12:11, 658495, 56854685, Joe, Appleseed, royal, 1970-01-01, +31684736248, null, Poplar St, 14a, 1012AB, London, null, joe.appleseed@overwatch.com, joe.appleseed@mindef.nl, null). (SQL: insert into \"users\" (\"wid\", \"unumber\", \"first_name\", \"last_name\", \"civil_status\", \"birthdate\", \"phone_number\", \"street\", \"street_number\", \"postal_code\", \"city\", \"email_address_overwatch\", \"email_address_mindef\", \"updated_at\", \"created_at\") values (658495, 56854685, Joe, Appleseed, royal, 1970-01-01, +31684736248, Poplar St, 14a, 1012AB, London, joe.appleseed@overwatch.com, joe.appleseed@mindef.nl, 2017-09-23 14:12:11, 2017-09-23 14:12:11) returning \"id\")
```

And here is the code that generates it, inside my `UserRepository`:

```
/**
 * Creates a new User with $data
 *
 * @param array $data
 * @return User
 */
public function create(array $data): User
{
    $data['password'] = bcrypt($data['password']);
    $user = User::create($data);
    $this->log(Auth::user(), $user, 'created');

    return $user;
}
```

I find this incredibly odd, as I'm definitely providing a value for password. I can see that by using `dd($data)`: (right under `$data['password'] = bcrypt($data'password');`

```
array:15 [
  \"wid\" => \"658495\"
  \"unumber\" => \"56854685\"
  \"first_name\" => \"Joe\"
  \"last_name\" => \"Appleseed\"
  \"civil_status\" => \"royal\"
  \"birthdate\" => \"1970-01-01\"
  \"phone_number\" => \"+31684736248\"
  \"street\" => \"Poplar St\"
  \"street_number\" => \"14a\"
  \"postal_code\" => \"1012AB\"
  \"city\" => \"London\"
  \"email\" => \"joe@appleseed.com\"
  \"email_address_overwatch\" => \"joe.appleseed@overwatch.com\"
  \"email_address_mindef\" => \"joe.appleseed@mindef.nl\"
  \"password\" => \"$2y$10$FdLbx/dYkdrjhGNcuCWKkO.bg013Gn0mhs7nKN.nyNztlykWx4jDC\"
]
```

As you can see, there is definitely a `password` field in this array. How is it possible that I get this error?

Some environment info:

```
PHP 7.1.9-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Sep  2 2017 05:56:43) ( NTS )
psql (PostgreSQL) 9.5.8
Laravel Framework 5.5.2
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `Hash::make($data['password'])`?

Comment: @lawrencecherone I don't think so. The standard laravel auth scaffolding uses bcrypt

Answer (score 5):

I'm guessing password is not [mass assignable](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#mass-assignment).  In your User model:

```
protected $fillable = [.... other fields ..., 'password'];
```

Comment: I thought so too, but check out https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/Http/Controllers/Auth/RegisterController.php

Comment: That's the default Auth scaffolding, and it uses `create() ` too